# Get UUID of a client computer in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vbscript

I need to generate UUID to eventually store in a database. Can I generate theses UUID from Javascript on the client browser ?

Can anyone tell me how/whether I can get a client computer identifier in my asp.net/or javascript ? (The client is in network not local Intranet)

(What is the client computer indentifier? I think such as: Client computer MAC Address, or any hardware GUID (like CPU, Network Card, etc. ) ?)

Currently I am generating UUID of a client by the following code using Activex in vbscript .

```
Public Function GetUUID(strComputer)

    Dim objWmi, colItems, objItem, strUUID, blnValidUUID

    Set objWmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colItems = objWmi.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystemProduct")
    strUUID = ""
    blnValidUUID = False
    For Each objItem In colItems
        strUUID = objItem.UUID
        If Not IsEmpty(strUUID) Or Not IsNull(strUUID) Then
            If (strUUID <> "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") And _
                (strUUID <> "FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF") Then
                blnValidUUID = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Set objWmi = Nothing
    If Not blnValidUUID Then
        Set colItems = GetObject("winmgmts:" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2").InstancesOf("Win32_NetworkAdapter")
        For Each objItem In colItems
            If (objItem.AdapterType = "Ethernet 802.3") Then
                If (objItem.Description <> "Packet Scheduler Miniport") Then
                    strUUID = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-" & Replace(objItem.MacAddress, ":", "")
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Set NicSet = Nothing
    End If
    GetUUID = strUUID

End Function
```

I do not want to use ActiveX anymore . Rather I want to do it by javascript . In javascript , I have found some code to uniquely generate some UUID as depicted in the following code :

```
var number = Math.random() // 0.9394456857981651
number.toString(36); // '0.xtis06h6'
var id = number.toString(36).substr(2, 9);
```

But for the above javascript code I am getting different UUID for the same client when running this script repeatedly .

On the other hand , the above vbscript generates unique id for the same client even . Even the script is run for a single client pc thousand time , the script generates the same id but for another pc it generates different id .

I want to do this . Can anyone help me to do this ?  (This is a business system, and customer is approved us to get their client computer hardware identifier, so how can i do in asp.net/JAVAScript? ) .

**Edit**
Basically I want to do it in Javascript beacause for ActiveX in VBScript , I can not run the script in any browser except IE . I want to overcome this limitations .

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into Browser Fingerprinting.
Fingerprintjs can be used for browser id: [fingerprintjs2](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2)
Also Check out [EFF's](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) demo